# F4 on Excel ranges, is it possible?

Tags: excel, range

I have an [Excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eUt4.png) with two worksheets.
In worksheet 1, I have an Excel table with three columns.
In worksheet 2, I want to perform some calculations on the Excel table.

Now, in F5, the formula is =NB.SI(mytab[col1];F4).
Now I want to duplicate the formula on the cells from left to right, by clicking on the + sign
in the bottom right corner of F5 and "spreading" it from left to right.
The [actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Amqzq.png) is that the range mytab[col1] is changing to the others range (mytab[col2],mytab[col3],..)
To obtain the desired result, I had to copy and paste the formula so mytab[col1] can't change.
Is there a way to lock the range by F4 ?

Actually this is a reduced example, in real world I have about 27 values rather than 5.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a table range, you can make ranges absolute like this: `=NB.SI(mytab[[col2]:[col2]])`

Answer (score 0):

The images you posted aren't much good - the 2nd one doesn't show the formula.

If you want to make the reference to `col1` from mytab absolute, i.e. it won't change as you drag the formula across you can use `mytab[@col1:col1]`.

```
=NB.SI(mytab[@col1:col1];F4)
```